# Can't install Haskell packages with cabal

Tags: haskell, package, compatibility, cabal

I read the suggestions on here of other people having cabal problems.   I'm trying to install both random and linear.  For linear I get an error that I need profiling version libraries.

```
mbp:~ ad$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 9.2.1
mbp:~ ad$ 

mbp:~ ad$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 2.2.0.0
compiled using version 2.2.0.1 of the Cabal library 

mbp:~ ad$ cabal install random
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed:
deepseq-1.4.6.1 (via: random-1.2.1 bytestring-0.11.1.0 splitmix-0.1.0.4) (new
version)
splitmix-0.1.0.4 (via: random-1.2.1) (new package)
bytestring-0.11.1.0 (latest: 0.11.2.0) (via: random-1.2.1) (reinstall)
(changes: deepseq-1.4.6.0 removed)
random-1.2.1 (new package)
cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
unix-2.7.2.2
process-1.6.13.2
haskeline-0.8.2
ghc-9.2.1
Cabal-3.6.0.0
libiserv-9.2.1
ghci-9.2.1
directory-1.3.6.2
hpc-0.6.1.0
ghc-boot-9.2.1
text-1.2.5.0
parsec-3.1.14.0
ghc-compact-0.1.0.0
binary-0.8.9.0
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.


Here is list of packages I have installed.

mbp:~ ad$ ghc-pkg list
/usr/local/lib/ghc-9.2.1/lib/package.conf.d
    Cabal-3.6.0.0
    array-0.5.4.0
    base-4.16.0.0
    binary-0.8.9.0
    bytestring-0.11.1.0
    containers-0.6.5.1
    deepseq-1.4.6.0
    directory-1.3.6.2
    exceptions-0.10.4
    filepath-1.4.2.1
    ghc-9.2.1
    ghc-bignum-1.2
    ghc-boot-9.2.1
    ghc-boot-th-9.2.1
    ghc-compact-0.1.0.0
    ghc-heap-9.2.1
    ghc-prim-0.8.0
    ghci-9.2.1
    haskeline-0.8.2
    hpc-0.6.1.0
    integer-gmp-1.1
    libiserv-9.2.1
    mtl-2.2.2
    parsec-3.1.14.0
    pretty-1.1.3.6
    process-1.6.13.2
    rts-1.0.2
    stm-2.5.0.0
    template-haskell-2.18.0.0
    terminfo-0.4.1.5
    text-1.2.5.0
    time-1.11.1.1
    transformers-0.5.6.2
    unix-2.7.2.2
    xhtml-3000.2.2.1
/Users/ad/.local/share/ghc/x86_64-darwin-9.2.1/package.conf.d
    (no packages)
```

I added the parameter to this file to enable profiling: ~/.cabal/config

I ran this unix command to rename the package database.

```
mbp:~ ad$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
To revert to previous state run:
    cabal update --index-state='2021-12-12T14:49:14Z'

mbp:~ ad$ mv /usr/local/lib/ghc-9.2.1/lib/package.conf.d /usr/local/lib/ghc-9.2.1/lib/package.conf.d.backup

mbp:~ ad$ cabal install --reinstall world
ghc-9.2.1: can't find a package database at /usr/local/lib/ghc-9.2.1/lib/package.conf.d
```

Of course it can't find package.conf.d, I just renamed it; I want to recreate it with all the Haskell packages needed to do compilations and add random and linear to the package database and have all these packages be compatible with profiling code too.

Can anyone please tell me what I need to do to accomplish that?

Comment: 1. Your cabal is a bit old. Might want to upgrade, we've made a lot of improvements, notably switching to nix-style builds by default. This completely eliminates the "reinstalls may break existing packages" problem. 2. A missing database is not the same thing as an empty database... and you don't want an empty database, anyway, because GHC comes with a bunch of packages that are really, really needed. If you must interact with a package database (why?), do it with the `ghc-pkg` command.

Comment: And please do yourself a favour and get used to _not_ installing packages, ever, but instead just depending on them and let Cabal worry about when they need to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

The course of action I'd suggest is:

1. Restore the package database you have renamed.
2. [As Daniel Wagner suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70343148/cant-install-haskell-packages-with-cabal#comment124347240_70343148), upgrade to the latest cabal-install (3.6.0.0 as of now). `cabal v2-install cabal-install` should be enough (it will install it for your user). On a related note, consider using [GHCup](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/) as a convenient way to manage the core Haskell tools.
3. [Set up a project](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/developing-packages.html) for the code you want to profile. [As leftaroundabout notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70343148/cant-install-haskell-packages-with-cabal#comment124349622_70343148), with cabal-install 3.x the natural way of managing dependencies is specifying what you need through the configuration of your project and letting cabal-install take care of the rest, rather than manually managing the installed libraries.
4. [Turn on profiling for your code through `cabal.project.local`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/nix-local-build.html#how-can-i-profile-my-library-application). With cabal-install 3.x it shouldn't be necessary to do that through global configuration (`~/.cabal/config`). See also [the cabal.project profiling options documentation](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-project.html#profiling-options).